# Mapbox - Create Colorize-Alpha Heatmap as Webapp

Tags: api, web-applications, mapbox, heatmap

The past year, I've used Mapbox Studio to create Heatmaps of point and linestring geojson data using the "colorize-alpha" style type.

Now I'm developing a web application which replicates the same heatmap unctionality in the browser.  I've tried the standard Mapbox API and the Mapbox GL API, however, neither seem to have the necessary functions implemented.

I see that I can upload my data to Mapbox's platform using the Amazon cloud.  From there I can style the data layer in the same way as Mapbox Studio.  However this is not nearly as scalable or simple of a solution as using the API or a plugin.

Is there a better way?  Can I build this functionality using just the API's plus some additional leaflet plugins, or will I need to download a webserver copy of Tilemill?

I'll post code specifics as a next step if needed.

Thanks in advance.